# What is the sentence pattern of a comparative sentence?

Tags: grammar

I want to know the sentence pattern of a comparative idea as, 1."Asia is the largest continent.
2.Asia is one of the largest continents."In particular what grammatical label can be given to the word 'continent'.

Comment: Question would be better iif you'd show a little working.  What do you think the label is? Why?

Comment: Surely a comparative would be "Asia is **larger than** Europe"?

Answer (score 1):

"Continent" is a noun and in the first sentence "the largest continent" is a noun phrase formed of "determiner adjective noun" forming the complement in an A is B sentence.

In the second sentence, "continents" is still a noun, in the plural form. The structure is a noun phrase "one of [plural noun phrase]" The plural noun phrase is the object of the preposition "of".

Comment: Could you please assist me to know what is the complete  sentence pattern of the 2 ideas which I have shared , Secondly what would be the pattern when both the sentences are converted into positive degree?

Comment: I've already done that. I've given a complete pattern of both sentences..  Come on, show some effort.  What do *you* think the complete pattern is? What do you mean by "convert to positive".